# How to embed google script (gs) content in html dialog

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a UI for my Google sheet and I have written my .gs function that returns the value I want. I have also written the HTML dialog that shows the window I need.

I know how to fill the dialog with static text, but I don't know how to put the value returned from the .gs function to be printed out in the dialog.

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    I want to have the value returned from the .gs function visible here as text. 

  <select id="simple" name="simple">
       <option> or even better here </option>
       <option>another option</option>
       <option>yet another option</option>
  </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

**gs**

```
function getCellContent() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("MySheet");
    var value = ss.getRange('A2').getValue();
    return value;
};
```

I feel like I've read the whole internet and found nothing about such basic things.

Comment: Read about `HtmlService` and client-server communication on the Apps Script developer reference. There is an entire guide about this topic

Comment: I've red it carefully, but there must be some error. Even copy and paste script from this guide, doesn't show scriptlet function properly. I don't know, what am I doing wrong.

Comment: There are `HtmlOutput`s and `HtmlTemplate`s which can be `evaluate`d and turned into a static `HtmlOutput`... Scriptlets require template -> output

Comment: @tehhowch, Thanks a lat, that exactly was my misunderstanding. I was trying to insert the scriptlet into HtmlOutput, and when I found out, it doesn't work, I've made a template, but did not show it. I was sure that the template modified the output automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scriplets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) to print the value into your HTML. For example

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1> Cell content: </h1>
        <p> <?= getCellContent() ?> </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm trying to, but it doesn't work. The scriptlet looks exectly the same in the script, as in the html window. I know, it works, because, when I forget one letter in the function name, error was returned, but after fixing the name, still in-spite of cell content I see all the scripitlet: <?= getCellContent() ?>.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was outside the code, I've attached.

There is another function which display the window on the screen. In my previous code it was:

.GS

```
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
```

But correctly it should appear like this:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
```

Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when I started with AppsScript. Plain html was rendering fine but scriplets inside the html was not rendering. The problem in my case was simple. Hers's a example that might be helpful for some.

So my `Code.gs` script contained:

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Menu')
        .addItem('Open Html Dialog', 'openDialog')
        .addToUi();
}
function getCellContent() {
    return 'Some content';
}
function openDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
                        .evaluate();
  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
}
```

And I had template named `index.html`

```
<body>
  <h1>Content: <? getCellContent() ?></h1>
</body>
```

Note that the above was failing because I was using `<?` which is parsed by most templating engines as regular JavaScript statements (eg. loops, conditionals, etc) instead of `<?=` which is used for evaluating an expression (something you want to evaluate and output to html view). So this (`<?=`) worked:

```
<?= getCellContent() ?>
```